# Design RESTful API for influxdb

Tags: mysql, api, rest, influxdb

I am designing the RESTful API for influxdb, but I don't know which pattern is better, and what's the better way to implement `group_by`, `sum`, `count` and choose endpoints.

### Sample Data Structure

```
Measurement(table): record 

time        user_id   aaa_id  bbb_id  ccc_id  duration

1460678400        1        1       1       1        30      
1460678401        1        2       1       1        11      
1460678402        2        1       3       1         1      
1460678403        3        1       1       4        24      
...
```

#### Which is the endpoint?

I don't know whether is better

```
GET /api/aaas/<aaa_id>/records
GET /api/bbbs/<bbb_id>/aaas/<aaa_id>/records
```

or

```
GET /api/records

with parameters ?aaa_id=<aaa_id>
                ?aaa_id=<aaa_id>&bbb_id=<bbb_id>
```

#### Count and sum implement

Because record has so many data, I only want the API return the count and the sum for duration field, not every single record. Below is what I thought now, but I don't know if there is a better way to do this

```
GET /api/records/statistic
GET /api/aaas/<aaa_id>/records/aggregate
```

#### Group by

I want to implement `SELECT count(duration) from record group by user_id, aaa_id`, but don't know how to make the API pretty

Answer (score 0):

Go through following samples

1)Measurement(table): record

1. /record - to fetch the points from that measurement
2. /record?opr=sum&field=duration - to get the sum of duration
3. /record?opr=sum&field=duration&stime=&etime= - to
   get the sum of duration between the time range
4. /record?opr=sum&field=duration&groupby - to get the sum of the duration
   grouped by each and every user

And using the above for **opr** param you can give values like count,sum,avg,min,max etch

field param=you can give either a single field name or list of fields as well